# Binding Image Dynamically in Metro App

Tags: c#, xaml, microsoft-metro

I have an ImageSource inside ImageBrush which would be changed dynamically depends on my data.

The problem is, I can't directly access the Name of the ImageBrush because it's inside DataTemplate. I know this is bad idea, because storing data inside UI is such a bad habit.

If anyone know how to solve this using data binding on Image, i would really appreciate that.
Thanks!!

```
<DataTemplate>
  <StackPanel Width="250" Height="180" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
    <StackPanel.Background>
       <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding ???}"/>
    </StackPanel.Background>
    ........
  </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: What are you trying to bind it to? a property in your code behind

Comment: I'm trying to bind the image with the path of the image. is it possible?

Comment: Where is the path, part of the object in your stackpanel?

Comment: For Example 
<ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding ImagePath}"/>
then i have 
String ImagePath { get; set; }, so i add collection 
public List<Topic> img = new List<Topic>();
img.Add(new Topic("image.png));

public Topic(string imgName) ImagePath = imgName;

Answer (score 2):

You can create a converter that converts the path to an image:

```
public sealed class ImageConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        try
        {
            return new BitmapImage(new Uri((string)value));
        }
        catch 
        {
            return new BitmapImage();
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

and then in the XAML:

```
< Image Source="{Binding Path=ImagePath, Converter={StaticResource ImageConverter}}" />
```

Comment: sorry, can u explain what does ImagePath contain?

Comment: hmm, i don't know but that doesnt work. I have added the path=Assets\f2f.png, StaticResource imageConverter, <local:ImageConverter x:Key="imageConverter"/> in app.xaml. but what i got is blank image :/

Comment: check the build action of you image

Answer (score 0):

try this instead:

```
<Image> 
    <Image.Source> 
        <BitmapImage UriSource=”{Binding ImagePath}” /> 
   </Image.Source> 
</Image>
```

Comment: I can't use <image> inside <StackPanel.Background>

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a property and bind the control to the property !!!
You can set the path of the image into the property and then Bind the element to the property

Comment: how would i set the datacontext? I mean to refer the source of the binding

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify `BaseUri` in `new Uri(BaseUri, Url)`

```
public sealed class ImageConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        try
        {
            return new BitmapImage(new Uri(BaseUri, (string)value));
        }
        catch 
        {
            return new BitmapImage();
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Also specify the converter in your XAML code

```
<Page:Resources>
     <local:ImageConverter x:Key="imageConverter"/>
</Page:Resources>
```

And Converter in your `Image`

```
<Image Source="{Binding Path=ImagePath, Converter={StaticResource imageConverter}}" />
```